# Add a theme via symlink

Tags: theme-development, directory

I want to keep my theme files separate from my WordPress install.
I’ve done that by symlinking the theme directory to the WordPress `wp-content/themes` directory.

Unfortunately, the theme won’t show up in the WP backend. My guess is, that WordPress does not follow the symlink. Any ideas how to do that?

---

I found [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165785/symlink-a-directory-to-wp-content-themes) which tries to do the same, but with Vagrant as an extra layer of complexity. Both answers on that topic did not help.

Comment: you linked the theme dir to the themes dir? as in themes=theme? or themes contains the symlink to the theme?

Comment: I symlinked the dir of the theme (my-theme) to the themes directory. (wp-content/themes/my-theme). So themes contains the symlink to the theme.

Comment: you could use this instead https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_theme_directory/, wp uses scandir and is_dir to find theme directories, you'd have to edit core files to make it work with symlinks.

Comment: scandir and is_dir PHP functions respect symlinks. Are you sure the directory is accessible by apache in the first place? Is there an open_basedir restriction in place? If so you may be SOL